# Company of Heroes 2 on Mac

Tags: steam, macos, company-of-heroes-2

I just bought the Relic Humble Bundle and redeemed the Steam codes. According to the Company of Heroes 2 Steam store page, and the Humble Bundle website, CoH2 is not Mac compatible. However, after redeeming them on my Mac, CoH2 shows up under Mac games in my profile. This only happens for CoH2 and not any of the other games in the Humble Bundle (including any of the CoH2 expansion packs).

Is this a glitch or is it actually Mac compatible?

[image]

There is an install button.

[image]

**Update:**
Appears to be a glitch in Steam. After clicking download, nothing downloads and the button converts to a Play button. At this point, it fails with a "no executable found" error, so it appears to be a glitch in Steam.

Comment: Is there an Install button?

Comment: The weird thing is yes, there is an install button.

Comment: Push it and let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Company Of Heroes 2 is not compatible with Mac.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Company_of_Heroes_2):

> Platform(s) : Microsoft Windows, Linux

**However**, you can apparently play the game on a Mac **using a software called Boot Camp**.

From a [Steam Community discussion](http://steamcommunity.com/app/231430/discussions/0/864971765190013799/):

> I'm running the game on bootcamp and it works pretty well. I haven't had any performance issues so far.

---

This does not apply to you, however, the Linux version is not currently released but the release date is to be announced, and it is due to be released some time in 2015.

Also from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Company_of_Heroes_2):

> Linux
>
> TBA 2015

Answer (score 1):

CoH is only on PC, and it appears to be a glitch. Nothing gets downloaded when I click download, after downloading zero bytes and clicking play there is an error that no executable was found. So it appears to just be a glitch in Steam.

Answer (score 1):

Coming to SteamOS/Linux

Company of Heroes 2 will be available on SteamOS and Linux in 2015.

ref: http://store.steampowered.com/app/231430/

I am guessing they're getting ready for it to be launched onto OS/Linux computers. 
Your welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Update for you all, the mac build is now on steam. I fired it up last night.

Comment: @Studoku - Uh, it kinda does - the other answers are out of date and this one is an *answer*, although it'd be better if it were more fleshed out. @ Ryan - any chance you could expand on this? Link to the Steam store? Maybe some screenshots?

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue when trying to download the game from steam - any way to fix it? I tried clearing my local game cache and reinstalling.