# Can you download a Mac version of a Steam game you purchased using a retail key?

Tags: steam, macos, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, steam-play

I added Modern Warfare 3 on Steam using a retail key. The game wouldn't download properly, as in when I clicked install it would instantly say it's finished downloading even though nothing was actually download. I contacted Steam support and went through various steps to try to resolve the issue which ultimately ended with them telling me that the retail version of the game isn't compatible with Mac. When I pointed out that the Steam Store page of the game says it is compatible they told me that it's not the same as the Steam Store version of the game, which I found confusing.

So my question is, is there a way to get this Steam Store version? Like if I go onto the game page it says it's purchased. I'm not even sure if I'm asking this question right to be honest as I don't know the difference between a game purchased on Steam with money and a game purchased using a retail key. The only solution they offered was to download it on Windows, which really isn't a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by game purchased with a key, do you mean a CD key?

Comment: Yeah, a CD key.

Comment: Does MW3 show in your games library?

Comment: Yes, it's there and when I click install it starts downloading but immediately finishes saying it's complete and the Install button turns to a Play button but I can't play it because nothing actually downloaded. I've tried re-installing Steam and verifying the integrity of the game cache and neither worked.

Comment: Some games can be activated on Steam using their keys.  You can try to add it by going to the Steam client, choosing "Add a game" (it's in the lower-left corner on Windows), then choosing "Activate a product on Steam" and open the prompts.  Of course, not all keys work that way.

Comment: The question isn't about activating a retail game using steam, this question is about SteamPlay. MW3 is listed as a SteamPlay game (buy once, play it on mac/pc/linux), but @NeedsHelp purchased the retail copy. It sounds like Steam support has told them that only the direct from steam version is SteamPlay enabled.

Comment: @Yorik Thank you for putting it into clearer words. This is what I mean. So the real question I guess is can I make it Steam play enabled? Or are they saying I have to buy the game again?

Comment: No you cannot - the retail version and the steam version are different games, just like versions of region locked games (ie an RU version and a ROW version) are different games

Comment: If the retail version doesn't run on mac, adding it to Steam won't change that. It's really sad how they limit users by this, since Steam versions are basically the same game with a few extra things and those often run on mac. Steam and retail copies are not interchangeable. If you want a Steam version of an already owned retail copy (or vice versa), you'll have to buy it again.

Comment: Is it even possible to purchase a game again if it is already in your library?  I know you can gift games, but I mean purchasing the game again for yourself.

Comment: @camelCase You can only gift it. This is what I find confusing, which is maybe due to me not fully understanding Steam, but it's not like I bought a retail copy of the game, installed it, registered it with Steam and am then unable to play it. I added it to Steam using a key given to me by my company. If Steam needs a Steam version of the game to run on Mac why isn't that the version that it downloads when I click install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you download a Mac version of a Steam game you purchased using a retail key?

Yes, but this will depend on the game.  For example, **[Orange Box](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1267062)** seems to work fine on multiple platforms when using the retail copy.

> I contacted Steam support and went through various steps to try to resolve the issue which ultimately ended with them telling me that the retail version of the game isn't compatible with Mac and when I pointed out that the Steam Store page of the game says it is compatible they told me that it's not the same as the Steam Store version of the game, which I found confusing.

Specifically for Modern Warfare 3, Steam support have told you that you cannot download your PC retail copy to a Mac via Steam.

According to **[Steam Play documentation](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9439-QHKN-1308)**:

> Steam Play allows you to purchase your games once and play anywhere. Whether you have purchased your Steam Play enabled game on a Mac or PC (both Windows and Linux), you will be able to play on the other platform free of charge.

It is not clear here, but essentially this applies to games purchased directly via the Steam store.  You can reasonably assume this information is specific to the Steam store because the same article also states:

> Look for the Steam Play icon... or ... ***when shopping on Steam.***

I agree that it is confusing.  Steam should specifically state the limitations of Steam Play.  Regardless, your problem with Modern Warfare 3 also applies to other games.  I found **[similar problems with Bioshock Infinite](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/3yq0m9/publishers_are_placing_steam_key_product/)** and **[Company of Heroes 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221428/company-of-heroes-2-on-mac)**.

In order to get the game to run on your mac you may need to look into virtual machines, emulation etc.  See **[this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17280/can-i-run-pc-steam-games-on-a-mac?rq=1)** for suggestions.

As mentioned in the comments, it doesn't look like you can purchase a Steam copy and use on an account that already has the game registered.  Perhaps you can gift it to a second account, and then use this second account exclusively for Modern Warfare 3.

Note, I can only speculate the reasons for such an implementation.  I would imagine the sales from Steam (directly) are more likely to go towards recouping the investment of porting to other platforms.... as opposed to a PC retail copy.